# How to position custom map controls above "Google" label in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have this so far.

[image]

Sorry for the blinkiness my computer screenshots isn't working so I gotta resort to this thing.

Anyways, the "Satellite" button should go above the "Google" sign with some space below, and left aligned. I have essentially this:

```
container = document.createElement("div")
ReactDOM.render(<div>Satellite</div>, container)
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(container)

mapOptions =
  disableDefaultUI: true
  zoomControl: true
  zoom: 13
  styles: [{ featureType: "poi", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]}]
  mapTypeControl: true

map.setOptions(mapOptions)
```

What am I doing wrong? I would like to not have to resort to CSS hacks if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the position of the controls by using

```
map.setOptions({
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
    }
})
```

or any of the enums listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/control#ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT) with a demo [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning).

**It's not possible to set a custom pixel or % position on those controls without resorting to custom CSS.**

This is perfectly fine, even the official docs provide [examples for this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-replacement)!

In your case that would mean, for instance,

```
.gmnoprint + .gmnoprint {
    left: -4px !important;
    bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

resulting in

[image]

---

What's usually done in these situations is hiding the google-default controls, [creating your own](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) `div`s and `button`s and then binding their click events to the gmaps API.

With that being said, after you've created & positioned a button to turn on the `satellite` map type, the listener's content can be as simple as

```
map.setOptions({
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
})
```

and getting the currently set ID is returned calling `map.getMapTypeId()`.

Comment: @alien if it helped you, mind accepting the answer?